# How can Python be used to write line breaks to a csv as '\n'?

Tags: python, csv, newline

I need to redefine the following code so that any line breaks in the row data (that would show up as a blank line) show as `'\n'` in the written file.

However, `'\n'` needs to be written after each row to show up as a blank line.

Each row apparently needs to be encoded as 'utf-8' to avoid errors.

```
with open('csvfile.csv', 'w') as csvOutput:
    testData = csv.writer(csvOutput, delimiter='|', escapechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    for row in data:
        newRow = [row[x].encode('utf-8') for x in xrange(len(row))]
        testData.writerow(newRow)
        testData.writerow(['\n'])
```

Comment: Try `testData.writerow('\\n')` if you want to get `\n` in the output file..

Comment: Where are the linebreaks you want to escape? Are there any in the actual row content, meaning `row[x].replace('\n', '\\n').encode('utf-8')`? Or do you mean that the empty row between each row should have an escaped linebreak, meaning `testData.writerow(['\\n'])`?

Comment: Yes, I just tried @101's suggestion for replacing line breaks in the row content which worked. Feel free to format as an answer if applicable.

Answer (score 9):

You need to manually replace newlines with `\n` using the [`replace` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Set the [`lineterminator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) option to the desired character sequence.  More info on what else is available is in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters).

```
with open('csvfile.csv', 'w') as csvOutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvOutput, delimiter='|', escapechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, lineterminator='\n')

    for row in data:
        writer.writerow([s.replace('\n', '\\n').encode('utf-8') for s in row])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this appears to keep the blank lines in the row data. In the initial comments, someone mentioned `'\\n'``, and row[x].replace('\n', '\\n').encode('utf-8')` successfully replaced the blank lines with '\n'

Comment: If the newlines is in the _data_ itself, you'll have to replace those on your own with literal `\n` sequences. You can do the replacement as you generate the new rows.

Comment: This sucks. I would expect csv module to handle escaping automatically instead of relying on user specified hacks like this. It sorta defeats the purpose of using the csv module, instead of relying on python string split myself.

Comment: @JohnJiang I disagree. It's doing exactly what it should be doing, taking rows of data and and formatting it to the csv specification. Granted, it would always be nice that it did a little more with more customizability. It doesn't alter what the data is or what it means, that's not what it was meant to do. To put it bluntly, the data contains the character sequence `'\n'`, it _must_ preserve it. If you want to change the data so that sequence is different, that has to be done separately. How that is done depends on how it is designed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it is to do with the `\` being an escape character in Python. `\\` is interpreted to be the actual `\` string. So your code should be as follows:

```
with open('csvfile.csv', 'w') as csvOutput:

    testData = csv.writer(csvOutput, delimiter='|', escapechar=' ', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)


    for row in data:
        newRow = [row[x].encode('utf-8') for x in xrange(len(row))]
        testData.writerow(newRow)
        testData.writerow('\\n') #Note the final row with \\
```