# Python script not writing results in new rows - newbie

Tags: python, html, css, csv

I am scraping an IMDB page for data but when trying to write it to a CSV file, I only get the last row from the results.

Below the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url='http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=sci_fi&title_type=feature&sort=user_rating,desc'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup=soup(page_html,"html.parser")

images=page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"lister-item-image float-left"})

containers=page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"lister-item-content"})

filename="scifi.csv"
f=open(filename,"w")

headers="order, title, year"'\n'

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
   number=container.h3.findAll("span",{"class":"lister-item-index unbold text-primary"})
   order=number[0].text

   atitle=container.h3.findAll("a")
   title=atitle[0].text

   date=container.h3.findAll("span",{"class":"lister-item-year text-muted unbold"})
   year=date[0].text
   print("order:" + order)
   print("title:" + title)
   print("year:" + year)

f.write(order + "," +title+ "," +year + '\n')
f.close()
```

I am using Anaconda & Spyder. For the love of me after watching youtube, searching on google, I still cannot understand why in the hell it is not writing in all the rows one after another. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you only have a single `f.write(...)` call, directly outside of your for-loop body. So, I suspect that is the reason.

Comment: Please show expcted output and what your code currently outputs. What were the results from using a debugger? I'm also pretty sure the HTML and CSS tags are irrelevant, as you yourself aren't directly working with them and it's unlikely the problem is with those parts.

Comment: Also, you should really be using the `csv` module to create csv's.

Comment: did you try using the `csvwriter` as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134439/how-can-python-be-used-to-write-line-breaks-to-a-csv-as-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your f.write was outside of your for-loop, so it was only writing that last row. This should work:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url='http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=sci_fi&title_type=feature&sort=user_rating,desc'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup=soup(page_html,"html.parser")

images=page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"lister-item-image float-left"})

containers=page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"lister-item-content"})

filename="scifi.csv"
f=open(filename,"w")

headers="order, title, year"'\n'

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
   number=container.h3.findAll("span",{"class":"lister-item-index unbold text-primary"})
   order=number[0].text

   atitle=container.h3.findAll("a")
   title=atitle[0].text

   date=container.h3.findAll("span",{"class":"lister-item-year text-muted unbold"})
   year=date[0].text
   print("order:" + order)
   print("title:" + title)
   print("year:" + year)
   f.write(order + "," +title+ "," +year + '\n')

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your f.write line under for loop. i.e. Add indentation to match with for loop body.