# Parsing a table in a HTML document into a csv using Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have the below table in a html document:-

```
<BODY>

<TABLE cellspacing=0 class="emlhdr"><TBODY><TR style="font-size: 1px"><TD style="border: none; padding: 0px">&nbsp;</TD></TR>
</TBODY></TABLE><!-- BEGIN_EXCLUDE_MORE_DATA -->
<TABLE cellspacing=1 class="ad"><TBODY>
<TR class="even"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>Title: </NOBR></TH><TD>Sample Title</TD></TR>
<TR class="odd"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>Site: </NOBR></TH><TD> Sample Site </TD></TR>
<TR class="even"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>URLIcon: </NOBR></TH><TD><style type="text/css">
</style>
</TD></TR>
<TR class="odd"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>URL: </NOBR></TH><TD><style type="text/css">
</style>
</TD></TR>
<TR class="even"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>Form: </NOBR></TH><TD>HistoryListEntry</TD></TR>
<TR class="odd"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>Collaborators: </NOBR></TH><TD>1.&nbsp;&nbsp;John Doe<br>
2.&nbsp;&nbsp;Jane Doe<br>
3.&nbsp;&nbsp;Jack Doe</TD></TR>
<TR class="even"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>SourceForm: </NOBR></TH><TD>Reply</TD></TR>
<TR class="odd"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>$UpdatedBy: </NOBR></TH><TD>John Doe</TD></TR>
<TR class="even"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>$Revisions: </NOBR></TH><TD>2/24/2020 9:37:13 AM +0000</TD></TR>
</TBODY></TABLE><!-- END_EXCLUDE_MORE_DATA -->
</BODY>
```

I am trying to parse the table so that the different entries go into columns in a .csv. Here is my Python 3.7 code so far:-

```
import os
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

output_row = []

with open(x, 'r', encoding="ascii", errors="surrogateescape") as f:
    s = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml') # Parse the HTML as a string
    table = soup.find_all('table')[1] # Grab the first table
    for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
        columns = table_row.findAll('td')
        for column in columns:
            output_row.append(column.text)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for x in output_row:
        writer.writerows(x)
```

This appears to work find and extracts the data but I can't seem to align it to columns. What I would like is for each 'TR class' text values to be in a new column in the .csv. So the .csv would have 9 columns with

```
'Sample Title', 'Sample Site', '', '', 'HistoryListEntry', '1. John Doe 2. Jane Doe 3. Jack Doe', 'Reply', 'Joe Doe', '2/24/2020 9:37:13 AM +0000'
```

respectively in them.

Any suggestions on the ammendments I need for my code?

With thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `output_row` seems to represent a single row, so you just need to write this row to your csv file (using `writerow` and without the `for` loop):

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(output_row)
```

For handling multiple data records, you will need a list of lists and iterate over the outer list (see also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704244/writing-python-lists-to-columns-in-csv/17704312)).

Also beware of the line breaks in your data fields, you should [probably replace them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134439/how-can-python-be-used-to-write-line-breaks-to-a-csv-as-n) to get a proper result.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
html = '''<BODY>
<TABLE cellspacing=0 class="emlhdr"><TBODY><TR style="font-size: 1px"><TD style="border: none; padding: 0px">&nbsp;</TD></TR>
</TBODY></TABLE><!-- BEGIN_EXCLUDE_MORE_DATA -->
<TABLE cellspacing=1 class="ad"><TBODY>
<TR class="even"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>Title: </NOBR></TH><TD>Sample Title</TD></TR>
<TR class="odd"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>Site: </NOBR></TH><TD> Sample Site </TD></TR>
<TR class="even"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>URLIcon: </NOBR></TH><TD><style type="text/css">
</style>
</TD></TR>
<TR class="odd"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>URL: </NOBR></TH><TD><style type="text/css">
</style>
</TD></TR>
<TR class="even"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>Form: </NOBR></TH><TD>HistoryListEntry</TD></TR>
<TR class="odd"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>Collaborators: </NOBR></TH><TD>1.&nbsp;&nbsp;John Doe<br>
2.&nbsp;&nbsp;Jane Doe<br>
3.&nbsp;&nbsp;Jack Doe</TD></TR>
<TR class="even"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>SourceForm: </NOBR></TH><TD>Reply</TD></TR>
<TR class="odd"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>$UpdatedBy: </NOBR></TH><TD>John Doe</TD></TR>
<TR class="even"><TH class="adlbl10"><NOBR>$Revisions: </NOBR></TH><TD>2/24/2020 9:37:13 AM +0000</TD></TR>
</TBODY></TABLE><!-- END_EXCLUDE_MORE_DATA -->
</BODY>'''

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# header = doc.selects('TABLE.ad>TR').select("TH>text()")
data = doc.selects('TABLE.ad>TR').select("TD>text()")
utils.save2csv('output.csv',[data])
print (data)
```

Result:

```
['Sample Title', 'Sample Site', '', '', 'HistoryListEntry', '1. John Doe 2. Jane Doe 3. Jack Doe', 'Reply', 'John Doe', '2/24/2020 9:37:13 AM +0000']
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples